# not able to set contraints for tableview in TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm not sure why I'm not able to set constraint for tableview in the TableViewController.I'm using swift language.

As per below link I should be able to do so.. but the option to set contraint is dsiabled in my tableviewcontroller.

http://vuta.info/dynamic-uitableviews-height-with-auto-layout-in-swift/

Please provide help on this issue.

Thanks

Comment: because you have taken tableviewcontroller.its tableview is the root view of controller and that should take whole screen size.if you want to resize tableview with constraints then take tableview in your viewcontroller not in tableviewcontroller.

Comment: what constraints do you want to add ? A `UITableViewController` is managing the tableView automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm if the below mentioned image suits to the requirement. I have deployed the code in Objective-c language however the design and constraints are same, Please visit the below specified the link for more details.

**Link**
https://github.com/joprithiviraj/TableViewCell_ResizeClass

Comment: **Image:**
![enter image description here][1]
  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gDCYp.png